# How can I import materials from another blender file with python?

Tags: python, materials, append

I have many files containing different parts of my blender internal material collection. How can I make a script which imports all of them into another blend file?

Comment: This is easily possible without python. Do you need to use python? (I'm pretty sure it's possible with python too) Or is a gui solution acceptable?

Comment: I would need to do it many times and on many files, and it would go nicely with the script i have already made. i know that you can press Shift+F1 to import from other blend files.
It would need to be a python script.

Answer (score 9):

There is some archaic way you could do this with [`bpy.ops.wm.append()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.append) but a better way is to work with the api available via [`bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries).

```
import bpy

# using a relative path
path = "//file_name.blend"

with bpy.data.libraries.load(path) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.materials = data_from.materials
```

As a sanity check or for logging purposes, you can loop through what was appended and see if everything is there as it should be

```
for mat in data_to.materials:
    if mat is not None:
        print(mat.name)
```

As it relates to many files, it should be simple enough to extend the script to also loop through a list of filenames to append materials from. A final note, the materials appended have no users so make sure to stick them somewhere before closing your file.