# Is there a way to append all materials in a Blender files with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, append

What I usually do is assign all my materials to a Cube and append it, and the materials just come with it.

The problem is that `bpy.ops.wp.append()` require a filename, and I have no way that I know to create a for loop that would cycle through all the mats in the file and append them. Usually when I want to import all files in a folder I use `glob.glob()` to create a list but that obviously wouldn't work in this case. Is there an equivalent to `glob.glob()` for a blend file?

Appending the cube has it's limit since I need to remember to assign my materials to it, and when you are working with hundreds of mats it becomes problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example using [BlendDataLibraries](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries) based on [How can I import BI materials from another blender file with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9366/31447). The script scans the given directory for blend files and appends all materials:

```
import bpy
import os

blend_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/<USER>/..."):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".blend"):
             blend_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

# Append all materials from all blends within the folder
for filepath in blend_files:
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
        data_to.materials = data_from.materials
```

A little bit of housekeeping might be nice in this case:

```
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.materials = [m for m in data_from.materials if m.startswith("MATLIB_")]
```

Comment: Thank you I think I can work with that!