# How to export all materials from a folder with blend files as seperate blend file?

Tags: python, materials

I want to extract all materials from a set of blend files into individual blend files and save them to disk with python. How can I achieve this?

```
import os

# folder containing blend files

my_dir = r"C:\MyFolderLocation"

# all blend files in directory

blendfiles = [f for f in  os.listdir(my_dir) if f.split(sep=".")[-1] == "blend"]
```

I am not very familiar with the Blender-API.

Can somebody help?

Comment: what are these "individual blend files"?

Comment: Individual means in this case "Single"

Comment: Do you want to collect all materials from all blend files in a directory into one single blend file? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/161119/107598

Comment: Sorry for my description! No, i want to collect all materials from all blend files in a directory into seperate .blend files and save them.